# How to add a new Excel workbook in the office.js pane app?

Tags: office-addins, office-js

How to add a new Excel workbook in the office.js pane app?
In vba there is a workbooks collection to which you can simply add a new workbook but in the new javascript api there is no such thing. There is a worksheets collection but no workbooks collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point in time we don't have an API to expose more than the current workbook in our APIs, but support for this may come in the future.

-Philip, Software Engineer on the Office Extensibility team